# Use Google Places API to autocomplete input in subscribe form

Tags: google-api, google-places-api

For a commercial website, I would like users to fill out a field with their shop name, and if the shop is found by google, fill out the subscription form (for example: phone number, address, logo, etc).

My question: is it possible to use this Api with that?  I find that the terms of use are not clear.

PS : Sorry about my english :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short a few of the important terms of use are:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html#section_9_1

- You must not charge access to use your implementation of the Places Autocomplete API and it must be freely accessible to the public. Unless its part of a Mobile Application or you have a Google Enterprise agreement or obtained Google's written permission.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete.html#requirements

- You must show a "Powered by Google" logo with any data accessed using the Places Autocomplete API if you do no show this data with a Google Map
- If the Places Autocomplete API responses contains Listing provider information it must be displayed to the user.

If your implementation adheres to the terms of use, than it is possible for you to use the Places Autocomplete API for the purpose described.